# no decrease loss and val_loss

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, loss-function

I try to train a neural network for time series. I use some data from Covid, mainly the goal is knowing 14 days of number of people at hospital to predict the number at J+1.
I have use some early stopping to not over fit, but almost one time over two the learning stop at patience+1 and there is no decrease of loss and val_loss. I have tries to move hyperparameters like learning rate but the problem is always here. Any guess?

The main code is below and the whole code with data :https://github.com/paullaurain/prediction

```
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# fit a model
def model_fit(data, config):
# unpack config
    n_in,n_out, n_nodes, n_epochs, n_batch,p,pl = config
# prepare data
    DATA = series_to_supervised(data, n_in, n_out)
    X, Y = DATA[:, :-n_out], DATA[:, n_in:]
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1)
# define model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4*n_nodes, activation= 'relu', input_dim=n_in))
    model.add(Dense(2*n_nodes, activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation= 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_out, activation= 'relu'))
    model.compile(loss='mse' , optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
# fit
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=p)
    file='best_modelDense.hdf5'
    mc = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=file, monitor='loss', mode='min', verbose=0, save_best_only=True)
    history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=n_epochs, verbose=0,batch_size=n_batch, callbacks=[es,mc])
    if pl:
        plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
        plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
        plt.title('model loss')
        plt.ylabel('loss')
        plt.xlabel('epoch')
        plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
        plt.show()
    saved_model=load_model(file)
    os.remove(file)
    return history.history['val_loss'][-p], saved_model

# repeat evaluation of a config
def repeat_evaluate(data,n_test, config, n_repeat,plot):
    # rescale data
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(data)
    scaled_data=scaler.transform(data)
    scores=[]
    for _ in range(n_repeat):
        score, model= model_fit(scaled_data[:-n_test], config)
        scores.append(score)
    # plot the prediction id asked
        if plot:
            y=[]
            x=[]
            for i in range(n_test,0,-1):
                y.append(float(model.predict(scaled_data[-14-i:-i].reshape(1,14))))
                x.append(scaled_data[-i])
            X=scaler.inverse_transform(x)
            plt.plot(X)
            Y=scaler.inverse_transform(np.array([y]))
            plt.plot(Y.reshape(10,1))
            plt.title('result')
            plt.legend(['real', 'prdiction'], loc='upper left')
        
            plt.show()
    return scores

# summarize model performance
def summarize_scores(name, scores):
# print a summary
    scores_m, score_std = mean(scores), std(scores)
    print( '%s: %.3f RMSE (+/- %.3f)' % (name, scores_m, score_std))
    # box and whisker plot
    pyplot.boxplot(scores)
    pyplot.show()
    
#setting variable
n_in=14
n_out=1
n_repeat=5
n_test=10
# define config n_in, n_out, n_nodes, n_epochs, n_batch, pateince, draw loss
config = [n_in, n_out, 10, 2000, 50, 200,True]
# compute scores
scores = repeat_evaluate(data,n_test, config, n_repeat, True)
print(scores)
# summarize scores
summarize_scores('mlp ', scores)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You should ask this on Data Science Stack Exchange. I suggested the question to be migrated.

Comment: @RomainReboulleau I agree, the problem is not caused by the code, I guess using a shallower model will resolve the problem.

Comment: I am agree to migrate the question, how to do it preserving the bounty?

Comment: I have run your model and found no such problems in losses. The losses decrease perfectly. As @meTchaikovsky said in the answer, probably the problem is due to model initialization. Also I have used `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`

Comment: @hafiz031 I have just update my github with 'univariate_test.ipynb', I use 'seed' for replicability and 'tensorflow. keras' as you, you can not that the third try doesn't learn anything.

Comment: Use `LeaklyReLU` instead of `ReLU` and the problem will be fixed. Simply remove `activation="relu"` from `Dense()` and add another layer of `LeaklyReLU` after each of the Dense layers like: `model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))`. I ran your code with this change for 100 times (n_repeat=100) and this problem didn't occur for a single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at your weights after training. I assume your Neurons die due to `relu` activation as they output Zero for Input < 0.
[image]

> Unfortunately, the ReLU activation function is not perfect. It suffers
> from a problem known as the dying ReLUs: during training, some neurons
> effectively “die,” meaning they stop outputting anything other than 0.
> In some cases, you may find that half of your network’s neurons are
> dead, especially if you used a large learning rate. A neuron dies when
> its weights get tweaked in such a way that the weighted sum of its
> inputs are negative for all instances in the training set. When this
> happens, it just keeps outputting zeros, and Gradient Descent does not
> affect it anymore because the gradient of the ReLU function is zero
> when its input is negative.

From Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow Concepts, Tools, and Techniques to Build Intelligent Systems, Aurélien Géron, 2019

So to combat this problem remove the `ReLU` activations and use `LeaklyReLU` instead. So for your case following are the changes:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LeakyReLU # for leakly relu

model.add(Dense(8*n_nodes, input_dim=n_in))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(4*n_nodes))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(2*n_nodes))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(n_nodes))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(Dense(n_out))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
```

After changing your code as specified the problem should be fixed.

**But in general I'm with @meTchaikovsky, for time series data recurrent neural networks are better suited for modelling.**

Comment: Indeed, replacing 'relu' by  'tanh' (for instance) solves the issue!! But since I am doing a regression, it seems that 'tanh' is not really appropriate since I am expected positive value, what do you advice. 'tanh' only on hidden layer and 'relu' on outpout, the converse, other activation fonctions?

Comment: For the last/output layer you can stick to `ReLU`,  use `sigmoid` or simply no activation at all.

Comment: @AndreS. it is a regression problem (see, `mse` is used as the loss function). So `sigmoid` is not an appropriate activation function in this case. `sigmoid` is for binary classification.

Comment: @hafiz031 you can still use it for regression, its output will only be bounded within (0;1), but it predicts positive values.

Comment: @hafiz031, Indeed the Leakyrelu solves (partially) the problem, since now it  learn every time,

Comment: @hafiz031, Indeed the Leakyrelu solves (partially) the problem, since now it  learn every time, but the accuracy is slower... it is strange dor a such basic problem. For regression on time series everyone advice Relu... Anyway thank you!! But there is still something I don't understand

Comment: @Paul accuracy also depends on the initialization of weights and biases of the network. Here is a nice post (https://www.wandb.com/articles/the-effects-of-weight-initialization-on-neural-nets) on this. You may find it useful. Cheers!

Comment: @Paul oh wait! Accuracy? Isn't it a regression problem (predicting the number of people)? Although `keras` won't prevent you to calculate `accuracy` even if it is a regression problem, but `accuracy` is an inappropriate measure for a regression problem and most of the times it will just misguide the training process if `accuracy` is used as a metric for regression. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788577/6907424

Comment: I use the word 'accuracy' at the wrong place here, I indeed look to the loss. So now th network learn at each step, but the loss is a bit bigger than before.

Answer (score 3):

**Because the `data` is time series while only `Dense` layers are used in the model**, the problem is caused by **model initialization**. A model with a 'bad' initialization will constantly predict zero, as you will see by running the script below.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# fix keras random state
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/52897216/8366805
seed_val = 94
np.random.seed(seed_val)
tf.set_random_seed(seed_val)
# Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

# main
def series_to_supervised(data,n_in,n_out):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    for i in range(n_in,0,-1): cols.append(df.shift(i))
    for i in range(0, n_out): cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    agg = pd.concat(cols,axis=1)
    agg.dropna(inplace=True)

    return agg.values

n_in,n_out = 14,1
data = np.load('data.npy')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(data)
scaled_data=scaler.transform(data)
DATA = series_to_supervised(scaled_data[:-10], n_in, n_out)
X, Y = DATA[:, :-n_out], DATA[:, n_in:]
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.1,random_state=49)

model = Sequential()
n_nodes = 10
model.add(Dense(4*n_nodes,activation='relu',input_dim=n_in,name='dense_0'))
model.add(Dense(2*n_nodes,activation='relu',name='dense_1'))
model.add(Dense(n_nodes,activation='relu',name='dense_2'))
model.add(Dense(n_out,activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
# fit
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),epochs=20,)

pred = model.predict(X,)
print('model prediction, mean %.3f, std %.3f' % (np.mean(pred),np.std(pred)))

for ind in range(3):
    intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=model.get_layer('dense_%i' % ind).output)
    pred = intermediate_layer_model.predict(X)
    print('layer %i, mean %.3f, std %.3f, min %.3f, max %.3f' % (ind,np.mean(pred),np.std(pred),np.min(pred),np.max(pred)))
```

In this script, I saved the array `data` in OP's post, to `data.npy`, which can be found [in this repo](https://github.com/meTchaikovsky/tmp.git), for simplicity. Besides, I fixed the random seeds of `keras` and `train_test_split`, therefore, you will reproduce the scenario in which the trained model constantly predicts zero.

In fact, as you mentioned in your post, similar scenarios are not rare (and try a shallower model does not help), **I think the problem is `Dense` is simply not capable of dealing with time series, you need `LSTM` instead.** Try the code below, in which I replaced `Dense` with `LSTM`+`Dropout`, besides, I changed the activation function of the output layer to `tanh`.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model,Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,LSTM,Dropout

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# main
def series_to_supervised(data,n_in,n_out):

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    for i in range(n_in,0,-1): cols.append(df.shift(i))
    for i in range(0, n_out): cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    agg = pd.concat(cols,axis=1)
    agg.dropna(inplace=True)

    return agg.values

n_in,n_out = 14,1
data = np.load('data.npy')
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler = scaler.fit(data)
scaled_data=scaler.transform(data)
DATA = series_to_supervised(scaled_data[:-10], n_in, n_out)
X, Y = DATA[:, :-n_out], DATA[:, n_in:]
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.1,random_state=49)
X_train = X_train[:,None,:]
X_test = X_test[:,None,:]

wrong_ind = 0
for ind in range(100):
    print('working on %i' % ind)
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(4,name='lstm_0'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2,name='dropout_0'))
    model.add(Dense(n_out,activation='tanh'))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mse'])
    # fit
    n_epoch = 5 if ind < 99 else 200
    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),epochs=n_epoch,verbose=0)
    val = history.history['val_loss']
    if np.abs(val[0] - val[-1]) < 1e-4:
        print(ind,val)
        wrong_ind += 1
        
print(wrong_ind)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2,figsize=(12,8))
ax[0].plot(history.history['val_loss'],'r')
ax[0].plot(history.history['loss'],'b')
ax[1].plot(model.predict(X[:,None,:]),'r')
ax[1].plot(Y,'b')
plt.show()
```

the output is

[image: output]

Comment: I have shallow the model like you but the problem still persist. Can you post on some github, your whole code and data.pny? In order I reproduce it.

Comment: @Paul Sure, I’m currently not with my Mac, I will include data.npy later. Actually, the data.npy is just your data array as I mentioned in my post, but I will include it anyway.

Comment: @Paul I have uploaded `data.npy`, check out my updated post.

Comment: Indeed, I have just try your code and 35/100 the model doesn't learn anything.

Comment: @Paul Check out my updated post, given the nature of your data, use `LSTM` resolves the issue :)

Comment: Indeed it works, but it comes from the 'tanh' because even with LSTM if you put 'relu' you have some problems. Usually people recommand 'relu' for this type of regression, it is wired to use 'tanh' since the result is expected to be positive, no?